An error occurred when deploying PieCloudDB
During the deployment of PieCloudDB, after executing sudo ./install.sh --with-chartmuseum, when starting the Harbor service, I encountered an error:
Error response from daemon: manifest for goharbor/harbor-core:dev-arm not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.

I don`t know what's causing this issue.

It caused by a discrepancy between the image versions in the generated docker-compose.yml and the offline version. Replace all the image tags specified as dev-arm in the docker-compose.yml with v2.5.6. Then, execute docker-compose up -d to proceed.
